# How to preselect PrimeNG Dropdown Group values with async load

Tags: angular, observable, primeng

I try to preselect a grouped dropdown. I tested with FormControl and ngModel but both have same result. It only always selects the first entry. Selected value is an id (number). The selected Id and options are async loaded

Angular 11 / PrimeNG 11

HTML

```
 <p-dropdown
      [options]="lists"
      placeholder="{{ 'LIST.SELECT_LIST' | translate }}"
      [group]="true"
      styleClass="col-11"
      id="selectListDD"
      dataKey="value"
      (onChange)="onChange($event)"
      [formControl]="selectedList"
    ></p-dropdown>
```

Here the component code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.store.select(UserSelectors.user).subscribe((user) => {
        if (user && user.listWrapper) {
          //Set options
          this.lists = this.listSelectionService.groupListsForDropDown([
            ...user.listWrapper,
          ]);
          if (this.listWrapper) {
            //Preselect dropdown
            this.selectedList.setValue(this.listWrapper.id);
          }
        }
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.store.select(ListSelectors.list).subscribe((list) => {
        this.listWrapper = list;
        if (this.lists && this.listWrapper) {
          //Preselect dropdown
          this.selectedList.setValue(this.listWrapper.id);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

With each change of setValue the first entry is selected. But if the component change the FormControl it has the correct value.

Any idea to fix it?